# Set the thickness of ant design icons in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, ant-design-pro

[Attached Image of icon to set the thickness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdfKD.png)

I have tried to set the thickness of the circle using stroke and stroke-width in css but none of them worked. The icon is imported from the antdesign .
Anybody can help with this? Much appreciated. Thanks

Currently my code looks like this(React)

```
<PlusCircleOutlined
    style={{
         fontSize: "50px",
         color: "#408021",
         storke: "#408021",
         strokeWidth: "2px",
        }}
 />
enter code here
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo error "storke", should be "stroke", but this is not the problem. To make the lines more thickness you will need to use the `stroke` property equal `white` or equal to the background color to erase part of the filled area:

```
  <PlusCircleOutlined  style={{
        fontSize: "50px",
         color: "#408021",
         strokeWidth: "30", // --> higher value === more thickness the filled area
         stroke: "white" 
  }}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it really worked. But there is one problem. If I set the stroke width as 30, there happens white outer border when the icon is placed on the image. Could you suggest a way to set the thickness not affecting the back ground color?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo: `storke: "#408021"`. Update that to `stroke` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to keep my styles in the css, so I did:

-In my jsx:

```
<PlusCircleOutlined className="icon-bold" />
```

-And in my styles:

```
.icon-bold {
  stroke-width: 25;
  stroke: black;
  color: black;
}
```